# How to efficiently Retrieve Open Event Details or Bounce Event Details given SubscriberKey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api

I am trying to get all tracking data events based on the subscriber key (email). 
Using the [Retrieve Sent Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job.htm), [Retrieve Open Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_open_events_details.htm), and [Retrieve Bounce Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_bounce_event_details.htm) pages as a template, I've written some code using the SFMC SOAP API to try to filter based on SubscriberKey. However, the request times out. If I try to filter based on SendID as in the example, the request returns immediately. This leads me to believe that the data views do not have an index on SubscriberKey to query efficiently.

I figured out that I can efficiently retrieve sent events by filtering based on SubscriberID, instead. This solves my task for the Sent Events because I can request "Subscriber" for a SubscriberKey, and get the SubscriberID, and then Retrieve Sent Event efficiently.

The code for this looks like:

```
String emailToTest = "exampleemail@bh.exacttarget.com";
String subscriberID = getSubscriberID(emailToTest).toString();

Soap stub = getSoap();
RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
request.setObjectType("SentEvent");
String[] stringArray = { "EventDate", "SubscriberKey","BatchID", "SendID", "SubscriberID"};
Stream.of(stringArray).forEach(s -> request.getProperties().add(s));
SimpleFilterPart filterID = new SimpleFilterPart();
filterID.setProperty("SubscriberID");
String[] filterValues = {subscriberID};
Stream.of(filterValues).forEach(s -> filterID.getValue().add(s));
filterID.setSimpleOperator(SimpleOperators.EQUALS);
request.setFilter(filterID);
RetrieveRequestMsg requestMsg = new RetrieveRequestMsg();
requestMsg.setRetrieveRequest(request);
RetrieveResponseMsg responseMsg = stub.retrieve(requestMsg);
System.out.println("Overall request status ::: " + responseMsg.getOverallStatus());
```

where getSubscriberID() submits a request for "Subscriber" using a filter on "SubscriberKey" with the email to allow mapping SubscriberKey --> SubscriberID.

*Again, this request works efficiently, and I am happy with it.*

**The problem** is that when I try a similar request using "OpenEvent" or "BounceEvent" instead, I get the error: Error: The Filter Property 'SubscriberID' is not a retrievable property.

If I try a different, working filter on SendID but still request SubscriberID as a prop, I get "Error: The Request Property(s) SubscriberID do not match with the fields of OpenEvent retrieve".

But in SentEvent, the "SubscriberID" also wasn't directly a field in the Data View, but was returned as a PartneryProperty list key-value pair.

Additionally, BounceEvent requests return the same error.

Why does SentEvent have SubscriberID as a property that can be queried, but cannot similarly retrieve OpenEvents or BounceEvents using SubscriberID?
How else can I retrieve OpenEvent or BounceEvent given a subscriberKey efficiently?

Comment: You see the fields that can be queried inside the documentation of the objects [Bounce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/bounceevent.htm), [Sent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm), [Click](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/clickevent.htm)

Comment: Hi @JohannesSchapdick, thanks for the comment-- I saw those docs, and in them, `SubscriberKey` is listed as one such field, but as I said, I haven't been able to query with it.